# UITableView insert static cell by using insertrowsatindexpaths

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview

I have a Reply button in `UITableViewCell`. On tap of Reply button, I have to display a `UITextView` right below it. How can I use `insertrowsatindexpaths` for this as the rest of objects in **datasource** array are of model type ?
I want to use `insertrowsatindexpaths` because I want to implement auto expand feature of `UITextView`. If `UITextView` is in an independent cell, there won't be layout issues.

Comment: `UITextView` can never be an independent cell. You need to add a `UITextView` to a `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: Also, to avoid conditional code, you should add a new model object to your datasource array and then insert rows/reload table.